# to determine the datatype of int, double using array as pointer to character string

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm sorry for my last post
I'm trying to find the size of the datatype using array
here is what I've done

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{

    char **type;
    int i;
    type =(char**)malloc(7*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {

        type[i]=(char*)malloc(12*sizeof(char));

    }
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {

        gets(type[i]);

    }
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {

        printf("%s",type[i]);
        printf("%d", sizeof(type[i]));

    }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know `sizeof` already, so you know how to find the size of a datatype. What are you inputing to that program and what exactly do you want out of it?

Comment: I want to declare an array of pointers to character strings then I want to Allocate memory from the heap for each string using malloc().and then using a loop to go through each entry of the array to print the size of the datatype.

Comment: So you enter strings like "int" and "double"?

Comment: yes but sizeof(type[i]) is not anything I guess
I don't know how to use array to find the size of datatypes like int, double, long

Comment: You can't get size of malloced space by using sizeof().

Comment: The thing that knows the size of types is the compiler. It's long gone by the time you run your code. You can't do what you're asking without you maintaining a list of type names and their size in your program.

Comment: then how should I proceed, please guide

Comment: `sizeof` is calculated at compile time not run time. You will have to build your own lookup table.

Comment: so in one array of pointer as string I declare all the data types and in separate array their sizes
am i correct ?

Answer (score 0):

```
      printf("%d", sizeof(type[i]));
```

ABove statement returning size of pointer instead of size of datatype.
Because type is char** and type[i] is char*.

What Output you got after running this program?

Comment: 8 8 8 8 .. like this something

Comment: Yes It will always give 8 for your code. Because you are printing size of pointer not sizeof datatype and you are always taking input in char *ptr so, this logic wont help to get desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do sizeof("int") because "int" is a `char *` so any string you try will be the sizeof `char *`

Try something like this:

```
int sizeof_by_name(char * name)
{
     if (!strcmp(name, "int")) return sizeof(int);
     if (!strcmp(name, "double")) return sizeof(double);
     if (!strcmp(name, "short")) return sizeof(short);
     if (!strcmp(name, "unsigned int")) return sizeof(unsigned int);
     if (!strcmp(name, "float")) return sizeof(float);
     // keep adding whatever types you want
}
```

There are more efficient lookups, but this should get you closer to where you want to be

Comment: working is good, but it's not elegant. Maybe a `struct mapper { char *name, int sz }` then `struct mapper cvt[] = { {"int", sizeof(int)}, { "char", sizeof(char)}...}; char * memallocs[] { malloc(cvt[0].sz), malloc(cvt[1].sz), ...};`  Keeping things bound together helps alot

Comment: I tried this, it works but just to clearify 
I want "array as a pointer to character strings" and this requirement can't be used like this or is it used. I'm a little confused

Comment: @user3192813 There is what you are trying to do, and what you possibly should be doing - this is advice on what you should try to do, not how to do things that can cause problems.  But, It seems you can do what you want with arrays of `char *` or struct now.

Answer (score -1):

u cant find the datatype just using sizeof operator. it just gives the memory allocated to it. ex int takes 4 bytes and float also takes 4 bytes or long long int and double.

one thing u can try is try to find .(period)  by traversing the string read. if present u can say it double or float( depending on your implementation and usage)

say if u use type's like int , float, double  and not to use long int , long double or any another types like these.Then u can diffrentiate the 4 basic types depending on the size and presence of .(Period)

Comment: is the .(PERIOD) operator is for operator overloading if yes then how can I use it in C, I think its in C++

Comment: Not operator sorry editted it. double you enter like 10.01 as a string it will be stored as 10.01\0 . u can search for the pattern of . in the string and differentiate btw int and double